# How to change the row height in excel using invoke vba dynamically in uipath

Tags: excel, vba, uipath

I have to change the row height in excel using VBA in Uipath. I have to pass a variable in VBA code which contains the row position at which I have to change the height.

I can write only static code like this .

```
Sub i()

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows("1")
        .RowHeight = 19.5
    End With

End Sub
```

Here I need to pass rows position dynamically as via variable from uipath using invoke VBA activity.

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1) .RowHeight = 19.5 `. `Rows(1) = Rows.Item(1)`. When use a string, it should be the worksheet name, not its index.  `Dim i as Long: i = 1`, then use `Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(i) .RowHeight = 19.5 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ChangeHeight(RowPosition As Long, dblHeight As Double)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(RowPosition).RowHeight = dblHeight
End Sub
```

To use, Entry Method Name is ChangeHeight and Entry Method Parameters are RowPosition and dblHeight

```
ChangeHeight(255, 14.5)
```

Comment: Hey thankyou for this amazing solution, entry method parameters should be passed like this in UiPath. :- {dblHeight,RowPosition}.

Comment: @karanarora, please do not forget to click buttons of appreciation when someone helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Write into a text file, e.g. `run.txt`

```
Sub RowWidth()
Rows(1).EntireRow.RowHeight = 19.5
End Sub
```

Now add a Invoke `VBA activity`.

Give it the name of the file `"run.txt"` and the 2nd will be `"RowWidth"`.